# Python dictionary inside a dictionary .title()

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I want just the country and the value capitalized.

This is my full code:

```
cities = {
    'rotterdam': {
        'country': 'netherlands',
        'population': 6000000,
        'fact': 'is my home town',
    },
    'orlando': {
        'country': 'united states',
        'population': 150000000,
        'fact': 'is big',
    },
    'berlin': {
        'country': 'germany',
        'population': 25000000,
        'fact':
            'once had a wall splitting west from east (or north from south)',
    },
}

for city, extras in cities.items():
    print("\nInfo about the city " + city.title() + ":")
    for key, value in extras.items():
        try:
            if extras['country']:
                print(key.capitalize() + ": " + value.title())
            else:
                print(key.capitalize() + ": " + value)
        except(TypeError, AttributeError):
            print(key.capitalize() + ": " + str(value))
```

From the output this part works, this is how i want it:

```
Info about the city Rotterdam:
Country: Netherlands
```

But i also get this:

```
Fact: Is My Home Town
```

How can i prevent every word in the value of ['fact']from being capitalized and have just the keys and only the ['country'] value capitalized using .title()?

so that i get:

```
Info about the city Rotterdam:
Country: Netherlands
Population: 6000000
Fact: Is my home town
```

Hope that i am clear.

Comment: It looks like you might need to change `if extras['country']:` to `if key == 'country':`

Comment: `if extras['country']` simply checks that the key exists at all, not that you are currently iterating through that key.

Comment: @GrantWilliams That worked! I tried that but did: if key == ['country'] it doesn't work... But if key == 'country' does work... Why is that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SeaWolf `key == ['country']` is comparing a `str` against a `list` whereas `key == 'country'` is comparing a `str` against a `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
if extras['country']:
```

to

```
if key == 'country':
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the answer above and it does appear to work in python 2.7.14 (don't ask...)

```
for city, extras in cities.items():
    print("\nInfo about the city " + city.title() + ":")
    for key, value in extras.items():
        try:
            if key == 'country':
                print(key.capitalize() + ": " + value.title())
            else:
                print(key.capitalize() + ": " + value)
        except(TypeError, AttributeError):
            print(key.capitalize() + ": " + str(value))
```

I got output

```
Info about the city Berlin:
Country: Germany
Fact: once had a wall splitting west from east (or north from south)
Population: 25000000

Info about the city Rotterdam:
Country: Netherlands
Fact: is my home town
Population: 6000000

Info about the city Orlando:
Country: United States
Fact: is big
Population: 150000000
```

Isn't this what you were hoping to achieve?

Comment: yes correct, the answer has been edited. Now it works! but i don't know what is difference in: if key == ['country'].